# conflicting types for 'distancia'

Tags: c, function

Tengo un programa que hace lo siguiente: Toma 2 pares de coordenadas, realiza las operaciones que estan incluidas en las funciones y larga la distancia que hay entre ambos puntos. El programa funciona correctamente si declaro la funcion "distancia" como int pero yo quiero declararla como float porque hay ciertas distancias que son con decimales.

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    int Tpunto1[2]= {}, Tpunto2[2] = {}, resultadoX, resultadoY;
    float resultadoDist;

    printf("ingresar x1: ");
    scanf("%i", &Tpunto1[0]);
    printf("ingresar y1: ");
    scanf("%i", &Tpunto1[1]);
    printf("ingresar x2: ");
    scanf("%i", &Tpunto2[0]);
    printf("ingresar y2: ");
    scanf("%i", &Tpunto2[1]);

    resultadoX = distanciaX(Tpunto1[0], Tpunto2[0]);
    resultadoY = distanciaY(Tpunto1[1], Tpunto2[1]);
    resultadoDist = distancia(resultadoX,resultadoY);

    printf("La distancia entre ambos puntos es de: %f", resultadoDist);
}

float distancia (distX, distY){
    float resultadoDist;
    resultadoDist = sqrt(distX + distY);
    return resultadoDist;
}

int distanciaX (x1,x2){ 
    int resultadoX;
    resultadoX = pow(x2-x1, 2);
//distanciaY = pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2)
//distancia = sqrt(pow((Tpunto2.x2-Tpunto1.x1),2)+(pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2));
    return resultadoX;  
}

int distanciaY(y1,y2){
    int resultadoY;
    resultadoY = pow(y2-y1,2);
    return resultadoY; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > El programa funciona correctamente si declaro la funcion "distancia" como int pero yo quiero declararla como float porque hay ciertas distancias que son con decimales.

Simplemente hay que cambiar la declaración a `float`.

**1.-** Las variables `resultadoX` y `resultadoY` deben ser cambiadas a `float`.

**2.-** Los *arrays* `Tpunto1` y `Tpunto2` también debe ser de tipo `float`, ya que sus elementos serán flotantes.

**3.-** Los valores que retornen las funciones `distancia`, `distanciaX` y `distanciaY` serán de tipo `float`, por lo tanto, debemos cambiar el tipo de valor que retornen esas funciones a `float`.

**4.-** En el primer parámetro de la función `scanf` en vez de usar el especificador `%i`, debemos utilizar `%f` (ya que esto le dice a `scanf` que va a leer un dato de tipo `float`).

**5.-** Cada vez que defines una función, debes especificar el tipo de dato que tendrá cada parámetro. En el código que propusiste no lo haces.

**6.-** Faltan los prototipos de cada función, de lo contrario, el compilador se inventará la declaración y esto genera un comportamiento indefinido (puede que la función no retorne el valor esperado en tiempo de ejecución).

Con los cambios mencionados, el código quedaría así:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float distancia (float, float);
float distanciaX (float, float);
float distanciaY(float, float);

//Según el estándar la función main debe retornar un valor
int main()
{
    float Tpunto1[2], Tpunto2[2], resultadoX, resultadoY, resultadoDist;
    printf("ingresar x1: ");
    scanf("%f", &Tpunto1[0]);
    printf("ingresar y1: ");
    scanf("%f", &Tpunto1[1]);
    printf("ingresar x2: ");
    scanf("%f", &Tpunto2[0]);
    printf("ingresar y2: ");
    scanf("%f", &Tpunto2[1]);
    resultadoX = distanciaX(Tpunto1[0], Tpunto2[0]);
    resultadoY = distanciaY(Tpunto1[1], Tpunto2[1]);
    resultadoDist = distancia(resultadoX,resultadoY);
    printf("La distancia entre ambos puntos es de: %f", resultadoDist);
    return 0;
}

float distancia (float distX, float distY)
{
    float resultadoDist;
    resultadoDist = sqrt(distX + distY);
    return resultadoDist;
}

float distanciaX (float x1, float x2)
{ 
    float resultadoX;
    resultadoX = pow(x2-x1, 2);
    //distanciaY = pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2)
    //distancia = sqrt(pow((Tpunto2.x2-Tpunto1.x1),2)+(pow(Tpunto2.y2-Tpunto1.y1),2));
    return resultadoX;  
}

float distanciaY(float y1, float y2)
{
    float resultadoY;
    resultadoY = pow(y2-y1,2);
    return resultadoY; 
}
```